# Ubuntu 16.04 mdadm automatically recognized raid 10 as raid 0

Tags: raid, mdadm

When a disk (out of 8 disk Raid 10 array) was physically removed, Ubuntu 16.04 recognized the the remaining disk as Raid 0.

Why is that? Restarting the machine doesn't help. It still recognizes it as Raid 0.

Where is the configuration to tell mdadm that the array is a raid 10 instead of 0?

Comment: Are you trying to add a disk back to a RAID 10? Or are you wondering why when you remove 1 disk is shows as a RAID 0?  See also:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_RAID_levels

Comment: The story was at first, 1 disk was disconnected due to a bad sata port, so mdadm detected that 1 disk was removed, but still detected as raid 10 at this point. And next I physically removed another disk, it is at this point mdadm starts to detect the array as raid 0, even after the second disk is connected back on. So I was wondering what has happened, how the raid level was determined as 0, not 10 after 2nd disk was putting back.

Comment: Interesting thing is once I connected the first disk back with a working port, and force assemble the array, it starts to recognize as raid 10 again, and the 1st disk needs to restore.

Comment: Were: `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf` - FYI Declare a faulty disk `mdadm --manage /dev/mdX --set-faulty /dev/sdbX` - Before removing a disk `mdadm --manage /dev/mdX --remove /dev/sdbX` - After adding a disk (replacement) `mdadm --manage /dev/mdX --add /dev/sdbX`

Comment: Trouble of declaring a faulty disk is you'd have to figure out which one is faulty. I saw somewhere saying it'd be fine to hot swap the disk, so I just disconnected it, then it starts to get out of sync i guess.

Comment: `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf` it doesn't show all the disks, only the array uuid i think?

Comment: If you dont declare `--remove` before a manual remove with no replacement, mdadm cannot always guess how to assemble the remaining devices

Comment: guess you're right, lesson learned.

Comment: `/etc/default/mdadm ` AND `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf`

Comment: If you want to run your RAID10 with 1 disk missing : `mdadm --create /dev/mdX --level=10 --raid-devices=8 /dev/sdaX missing`